# How can I remove this specific section of a string without also removing the 'm' in the list

Tags: python, string, list

This is my code now:

```
def extract_categories(line: str):
    new_line = re.sub('[ +++$+++]', '', line)
    newer_line
    print(new_line)
```

I want it to print this

```
['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']
```

but it prints this:

```
m448hrs.19826.9022289['action','comedy','crime','drama','thriller']
```

This is the input I am using:

```
"m4 +++$+++ 48 hrs. +++$+++ 1982 +++$+++ 6.90 +++$+++ 22289 +++$+++ ['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']"
```

I need the first part removed, I tried removing exactly 'm448hrs.19826.9022289' but then also  the m's from 'crime' and 'drama' disappeared, what should I do here?  Im new to python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a clear sample of your input…

Comment: It's unclear why you're trying to replace the +++$+++ parts of the string when all you want is the part that looks like a Python list. Try using *find()* to get the positions of the square brackets then slice the relevant part of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try breaking down the string based on pattern later you replace un wanted items as

```
st = "m4 +++$+++ 48 hrs. +++$+++ 1982 +++$+++ 6.90 +++$+++ 22289 +++$+++ ['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']"
new = []
mask = st.split(' +++$+++ ')[-1][1:-1].replace("'","").replace(" ","")
new.append(mask.split(','))
print(new[0])
```

Gives #

```
['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index()` or `find()` to find index of substring you want to print and slice the string from substring index to end of the string. `index()` will raise ValueError if the substring is not found, and `find()` will return -1.

```
line = "m4 +++$+++ 48 hrs. +++$+++ 1982 +++$+++ 6.90 +++$+++ 22289 +++$+++ ['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']"
line = line[line.index('['):]
print(line)
```

To avoid exception, use `find()` with conditional statement in your function:

```
line = "m4 +++$+++ 48 hrs. +++$+++ 1982 +++$+++ 6.90 +++$+++ 22289 +++$+++ ['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']"

def extract_categories(line: str):
    return line[found:] if (found := line.find('[')) != -1 else 'Not found'

print(extract_categories(line))
```

Or:

```
line = "m4 +++$+++ 48 hrs. +++$+++ 1982 +++$+++ 6.90 +++$+++ 22289 +++$+++ ['action', 'comedy', 'crime', 'drama', 'thriller']"

def extract_categories(line: str):
    return ('Not Found',line[(found:=line.find('[')):])[found!=-1]

print(extract_categories(line))
```